# Displaying numbers in moderncv showing symbols "W2 and 1099"

Tags: symbols, moderncv

I am trying to write out this sentence

```
Issued W2's to employees and 1099's to contractors
```

but when LaTeX processes it I end up with

[image: this].

I am sure it is a simple fix but for the life of me google isn't returning much and my knowledge of latex is limited. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduced the problem.  Other than that, I'd suggest retyping the sentence (not copying and pasting) and trying different apostrope's.

Comment: Are you maybe inputting "smart" apostrophes rather than just a `'`, aka a "dumb" or "straight" single-quote character? If that's the case, see if adding the instructions `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (in the preamble) helps.

Comment: You shouldn't have apostrophes here in any case: what is it that you claim belongs to 'W2' and '1099'? Unless you are talking about their possessions, apostrophes are incorrect.